# Adding user to multiple groups

Tags: google-apps-script

Im trying to automate onboarding in Gsuite utilizing google sheets. I want to automate group memberships.

I would like to know if the following syntax would work to add a user to multiple groups:

```
function addGroupMember() {
var groupArray = ["x@example.com", "z@example.com"]
var userEmail = "email";
var groupEmail = groupArray;
var member = {
     email: userEmail,
     role: 'MEMBER'
   };
   member = AdminDirectory.Members.insert(member, groupEmail);
   Logger.log('User %s added as a member of group %s.', userEmail, groupEmail);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is almost correct. You need to iterate over the `groupArray` to do one group at a time, also, `groupEmail = groupArray;` is redundant, as you can directly use `groupArray`, or change its name to `groupEmail`:

```
function addGroupMember() {

  var groupArray = ["group1@example.com", "group2@example.com"];
  var userEmail = "user@email.com";
  var member = {
    email: userEmail,
    role: 'MEMBER'
  };

  for (i in groupArray){

    AdminDirectory.Members.insert(member, groupArray[i]);
    Logger.log('User %s added as a member of group %s.', userEmail, groupArray[i]);
  }
}
```